# Как в excel настроить расчёт суммы при выборе параметров товара

Tags: excel, excel-формулы, формулы

Нужен способ расчёта суммы по разным параметрам.
Есть товар с параметрами: название, вес(тонн), длина(метр), количество, лента(параметры).

В excel нужно чтобы при выборе разных параметров стропы(товара) выдавало сумму.
**К примеру:** стропа1 весом в 3 тонны, длиной 8 метров, в количестве 1шт, лента 30*1. = столько то рублей. (при разных параметрах разная цена чтоб была)

[image: таким образом выбрать из списка свойство и чтобы получился результат в виде цены]

P.S.: гуглил формулы всякие находил всё не то, может макрос какой-то есть, как лучше сделать, может не екселем если есть варианты прошу помощи плиз :)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Добавьте пример - где находятся данные, где выбор параметров, где результат

Comment: Добавили картинку... Понятней не стало. Как цена формируется? откуда данные брать? Хотите видеть сумму. Это стоимость в одной строке или сумма строк с одинаковыми параметрами. Нужен нормальный пример. У Вас файл есть? Вот и сделайте небольшой пример на его основе